# how to get only values from single table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, mysql-workbench

I have only single table as shown below

| id | name | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sai | m |
| 2 | sai | EBB |
| 3 | sri | m |
| 4 | ram | m |
| 5 | sita | EBB |
| 6 | siva | EBB |

please help me to  write a SQL query to show only m , only ebb and both .
only m

| id | name | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | sri | m |
| 4 | ram | m |

only ebb

| id | name | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | sita | EBB |
| 6 | siva | EBB |

intersect or both

| id | name | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sai | m |
| 2 | sai | EBB |

i have tried using not except, joins but nothing worked for me.Please help me .

Comment: Please follow the guidance on this link to improve your question, as it is unclear at the moment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i tried my best to show the table . Please help me

Comment: I cannot. Please read the entire guidance, not just the first point!

Comment: @SriHarsha When you say "a SQL query to show only m", do you mean to display records with names that appear with product = 'm' but not with product = 'EBB'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery as follows

```
mysql> select * from tbl where name in (select name from tbl where product = 'm') and name not in (select name from tbl where product = 'EBB');
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | product |
+----+------+---------+
|  3 | sri  | m       |
|  4 | ram  | m       |
+----+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from tbl where name not in (select name from tbl where product = 'm') and name in (select name from tbl where product = 'EBB');
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | product |
+----+------+---------+
|  5 | sita | EBB     |
|  6 | siva | EBB     |
+----+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from tbl where name in (select name from tbl where product = 'm') and name in (select name from tbl where product = 'EBB');
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | product |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | sai  | m       |
|  2 | sai  | EBB     |
+----+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```